# Fan Maxes Out and Battery Status Indicator Flashes

Tags: 13.10, asus, battery, fan

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my Asus UX301LA which has raided SSDs and is in UEFI. Install is fine and everything works, however sometimes when I boot my fan maxes out and my battery status indicator on the power cord flashes. I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot as I'm fairly new.

If I were to boot into windows with the LED blinking it would say plugged in but not charging.

This laptop is brand new just received it about 3 days ago and hasn't always had these symptoms. The symptoms started after booting to linux. Also the fan doesn't max out every time. I know the laptop isn't hot since it's just booting so there is no need for the fan.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Any update on the charging/fan issue? Maybe a firmware update fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop and the same issue.

I successfully avoid the issue by not shutting it down, ever. I just suspend it and occasionally reboot it, and it works like a charm.

Here is a [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2193133&p=12903826#post12903826) with some other suggestions.

I reported this issue to the asus support and I got a really helpful "contact your nearest supplier and replace it".

Answer (score 0):

Try installing LTP, if you haven't already:

http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

It really helps to reduce power consumption as well as fan noise.

Answer (score 0):

The battery flashing means the battery is not full but also not loading. I have it too and taking it of the charger for a few minutes and then putting it back on it always fixes it for me.

It is hardware related though (and also pretty common(?)).